# ggplot stacked barplot order gets ignored

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following example, ggplots ignores my order when stacking the bars of the barplot.  Note that the order is respected in the legend.

1. prepeare the data:

   ```
   plotdf <-
     structure(list(.id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
     2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
     5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("C A", "C W", "C R", 
     "I N D", "I e", "I o"), class = "factor"), grp = structure(c(3L, 
     1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
     4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("C L", 
     "F C", "C", "B", "R"), class = "factor"), v = c(0, 0.239181693913566, 
     0.165857056803677, 0.350750434828833, 0.244210814453923, 0, 0.271188523388472, 
     0.0962040631815689, 0.272432818496037, 0.360174594933923, 0.0369015572477178, 
     0.29722089026182, 0.125321399722723, 0.195349629447893, 0.345206523319846, 
     0, 0.194564544482903, 0.30578720507121, 0.139178183673556, 0.360470066772331, 
     0.0263516505214496, 0.247452946164384, 0.400260126370759, 0.0579795532895398, 
     0.267955723653867, 0, 0.369045931493036, 0.372811575779409, 0, 
     0.258142492727555)), .Names = c(".id", "grp", "v"), row.names = c(NA, 
     -30L), class = "data.frame")
   ```
2. look at the data -- there are factors

   ```
   head(plotdf)
   ##   .id grp         v
   ## 1 C A   C 0.0000000
   ## 2 C A C L 0.2391817
   ## 3 C A   B 0.1658571
   ## 4 C A F C 0.3507504
   ## 5 C A   R 0.2442108
   ## 6 C W   C 0.0000000

   str(plotdf)
   ## 'data.frame':    30 obs. of  3 variables:
   ##  $ .id: Factor w/ 6 levels "C A","C W","C R",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
   ##  $ grp: Factor w/ 5 levels "C L","F C","C",..: 3 1 4 2 5 3 1 4 2 5 ...
   ##  $ v  : num  0 0.239 0.166 0.351 0.244 ...

   head(plotdf$grp)
   ## [1] C   C L B   F C R   C  
   ## Levels: C L F C C B R
   ```
3. plot

   ```
   ggplot(plotdf, aes(x=.id, y=v, fill=grp)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
   ```

   gives me [image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the factor levels specifies the order of values along the axis and in the legend. But for what ever reason, when you are stacking barplots, you must also set the `order=` aesthetic. Use

```
ggplot(plotdf, aes(x=.id, y=v, fill=grp, order=grp)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Works like a charm.  I for sure got some gray hair over this one.  I will remember that.  Just out of curiosity:  Is that documented somewhere?  Do you know?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where it's documented. I just know because someone asked a similar question somewhat recently ;)